# SSH to WebServer using PuTTY

Tags: web-server, putty

I am using 1Dollar-WebHosting.com to host my website.

I need to SSH to my WebServer using PuTTY.

When in cPanel, under the Security tab:

1) I click on SSH/Shell Access. 
 2) I then click on "Manage SSH Keys". 
 3) I then click on Generate a new key. 
 4) I save it with a passphrase to protect it. 
 5) I click Generate new key.

SSH key Generator tells me: Key Generation Complete!

6) I click "Go Back" and click "Manage Authorization". 
 7) I click "Authorize".

SSH Key Authorization tells me: "id_dsa.pub" has been authorized.

8) I click "Go Back".

I see that a private key has appeared under the "Private Keys:" heading.

9) I click "View/Download". 
 10) I type in the passphrase and click "Convert" to convert 'type file' to a .PPK file. 
 11) I download the .PPK key file.

In PuTTY:

1) I type in www.spellstorm-realms.com as the hostname. 
 2) Port is left as 22. 
 3) Under Connection, I expand SSH and click on Auth. 
 4) I browse for my PPK file. 
 5) I click on the Session tab. 
 6) I click Open.

Putty tells me: Network Error: Connection Refused.

Perhaps, someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a quick portscan port 22 is closed on your server. That is why you are getting connection refused. Check that the ssh daemon is running on your server and that the firewall on your server is configured to allow access on port 22

Comment: They say that SSH access is not available..